# Docker not found, even though it is installed

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I tried setting up a Docker environment for my developing ventures:

I installed docker using [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) "Install docker engine" from their website and receive the following output:

```bash
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
Paketlisten werden gelesen… Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut… Fertig
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen… Fertig
containerd.io ist schon die neueste Version (1.6.13-1).
docker-ce-cli ist schon die neueste Version (5:20.10.22~3-0~ubuntu-jammy).
docker-ce ist schon die neueste Version (5:20.10.22~3-0~ubuntu-jammy).
docker-compose-plugin ist schon die neueste Version (2.14.1~ubuntu-jammy).
Die folgenden Pakete wurden automatisch installiert und werden nicht mehr benötigt:
  cpu-checker ibverbs-providers ipxe-qemu ipxe-qemu-256k-compat-efi-roms libaio1
  libbrlapi0.8 libcacard0 libfdt1 libgfapi0 libgfrpc0 libgfxdr0 libglusterfs0
  libibverbs1 libiscsi7 libpmemobj1 librados2 librbd1 librdmacm1 libspice-server1
  libusbredirparser1 libvirglrenderer1 msr-tools ovmf pass qemu-block-extra
  qemu-system-common qemu-system-data qemu-system-gui qemu-system-x86 qemu-utils
  qrencode seabios tree uidmap xclip
Verwenden Sie »sudo apt autoremove«, um sie zu entfernen.
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 9 nicht aktualisiert.
2 nicht vollständig installiert oder entfernt.
Nach dieser Operation werden 0 B Plattenplatz zusätzlich benutzt.
Möchten Sie fortfahren? [J/n] j
```

then nothing more.
(well, my nvidia drivers are running bonkers at the moment.)

```bash
sudo docker run hello-world sudo: docker: Befehl nicht gefunden
```

I reinstalled maybe ten times now and have not a single clue how to pursue this further.

We run a dev-environment in docker that emulates a rather complex working environment, where servers push things to other servers etc. so I am depending on docker *a lot* and cannot work at the moment.

By now I am so confused, that I think starting from the beginning works best, thus I tried uninstalling following this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/935569/how-to-completely-uninstall-docker

Now nothing works, not even installing ...

any hint is highly appreciated